# How to override BindingAdapter for derived classes

Tags: android, android-databinding

I would like to define different `BindingAdapters` for a `TextView` and `EditText` with the same attribute name with different behavior.

```
@BindingAdapter("date")
public static void bindDate(TextView textView ...)

@BindingAdapter("date")
public static void bindDate(EditText textView ...)
```

It seems that the adapter for the `TextView` is used in all cases. I would expect, that the latter adapter will be used for an `EditText`.

Comment: This behavior occurs because EditText extends TextView. Your best bet is to have a different attribute name